# ASP.NET MVC Route does not work, why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ThreadList",
    url: "Forums/{category}/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Forums", action = "ThreadList" }
);
```

And it does not match this link:

```
http://localhost:11227/Forums/MyCategory
```

Where i made an error?

Comment: Send us all routes and in order. It could be just the order of your routes that is the problem

Comment: following up on what @terjetyl wrote, is any other route "above" this route is order? if standard Default route was above this one, it would look for Controller: Forums, Action: MyCategory

Comment: Phil Haacks "Route Debugger" is a tremendous help for debugging routing issues - http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger